# Content Type IDs help

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have 2 Content Types, A and B. I am trying to create Content Type ID's(not proper ID's) and completely separate from the ID already in the list. I am creating them as a calculated field but I cannot work out a formula to make it work.
Basically all I want is for it to be like this:

```
ID     A    B
1      1    1
2      2    2
3      3    3
4      4    4
```

Comment: You cannot use ID column in Calculated Field.. Unless the item is updated (after insertion), the ID field is not reflected in calculated columns.. You might need to look at Event receiver on ItemAdding set the A and B columns

Comment: Its completely separate from ID column.

Comment: I was wanted to show ID there for what I want the list to look like

Comment: Just want both to increment up